# Binding extra info in JiBX

Tags: java, jibx, xml-binding

Lets assume there is a `user.xml` which contains the actual user input [user info like name,address, etc.]

Based on that, certain java objects are created.

Now when it comes to `binding.xml`, I should definitely mention all the values given in the `user.xml`.

**Now my question is**: Will the binding work if i add extra information in any/all of the java objects(example: `String userContactNo` only in a java object and not in the `user.xml`) which is not mentioned in the `user.xml` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure,
You don't have to bind every field to an xml definition, only the ones that you want included in the xml.